# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
/*
bot.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;

const TicketToolEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Creat a support Ticket")
    .setDescription("React to this message to open a support ticket with the Server Administrators")
    .setColor("#B900FF")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("Ticket Bot System")



    message.channel.send(TicketToolEmbed)
        .then(message => message.react('✅'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

}); */

bot.on('raw', async payload => {
    let eventname = payload.t;
    if (eventname === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
        let msgId = payload.d.message_id;
        if (msgId === '712016328189411348') {
            let channelId = payload.d.channelId;
            let channel = Client.channels.get(channelId);
            if (channel) {
                if (channel.message.has(msgId))
                    return;
                else {
                    try {
                        let msg = await channel.fetchMessage(msgId);
                        let reaction = msg.reaction.get('✅');
                        let user = Client.user.get(payload.d.user_id);
                        Client.emit('messageReactionAss', reaction, user);
                    }
                    catch (ex) {
                        console.log(ex);
                        return;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        console.log("Creating ticket...");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Wrong emoji");
    }
});
```

Console:

```
(node:11924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\index.js:65:43)
at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:287:27)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:436:14)
at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:366:17)
at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\sande\Desktop\discbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:142:22)
```

(node:11924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11924) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've used `Client` instead of `bot` in all your code sample.

Try with the following :

```js
bot.on('raw', async payload => {
    let eventname = payload.t;
    if (eventname === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
        let msgId = payload.d.message_id;
        if (msgId === '712016328189411348') {
            let channelId = payload.d.channelId;
            let channel = bot.channels.get(channelId);
            if (channel) {
                if (channel.message.has(msgId))
                    return;
                else {
                    try {
                        let msg = await channel.fetchMessage(msgId);
                        let reaction = msg.reaction.get('✅');
                        let user = bot.user.get(payload.d.user_id);
                        bot.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, user); // Also corrected "messageReactionAss" to "messageReactionAdd".
                    }
                    catch (ex) {
                        console.log(ex);
                        return;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        console.log("Creating ticket...");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Wrong emoji");
    }
});
```